# Why didn't Jones answer Vuk's question?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-dark-phoenix

In *Dark Phoenix* (2019), after Jean faints Scott with her hands, Vuk meets Jones:

> Vuk: **So this is all that's left of the D'Bari Empire?**
>
> Jones: Greetings, Vuk. Have you learned their language?
>
> Vuk: With ease.

Why didn't Jones answer Vuk's question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no need. It is not a question, it is a(n unhappy) fact phrased like a question. A sad lament at the current state of the world,if you will.

An analogy is in order. Two high school friends meet after 20 years at the reunion.

> Vuk: My god. Have you really gotten that fat and bald or is my eyesight going, old friend?
>
> Jones: Hi Vuk. Have you learned German like you always wanted?
>
> Vuk: With ease.